# Scylla 1.4 could not setup on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, scylla

I trying to setup ScyllaDB on my Ubuntu 16.04 system. But I encounter the following error:

```
aims@aims:~$ sudo scylla_setup
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
[sudo] password for aims: 
Skip any of the following steps by answering 'no'
Do you want to run kernel version check?
Answer yes to have this script verify that the currently installed kernel is qualified to run Scylla; answer no to skip this check.
[YES/no]yes
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
scylla : Depends: scylla-tools but it is not going to be installed
xfsprogs : Depends: libreadline5 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried to find out solutions for it, but could not get it. Kindly, let me know where I going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to solve the `unmet dependencies` :

Add `scylla 1.4` repo to your `sources.list` :

```
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scylla.list http://downloads.scylladb.com/deb/ubuntu/scylla-1.4-xenial.list
```

Update your system

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Install `libreadline5` , it's available from the `main` repo :

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline5
```

Install `scylla`:

```
sudo apt-get install scylla
```

Run:

```
sudo scylla_setup
```

Enable/start sevices:

```
sudo systemctl enable scylla-server
sudo systemctl start scylla-server
sudo systemctl enable scylla-jmx
sudo systemctl start scylla-jmx
```

Comment: Is there any authentication to connect to scylla-jmx remotely?  I'm trying to connect to it via `jconsole xy.xy.xy.xy:7199` but it gets stuck. Firewall is open.

Comment: Please note that Scylla-1.4 is an unsupported version.